# Add VideoView in Android views according to number of files

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I add `VideoView` programmatically according to the number of videos in specified folder? Any suggestions please or some links to learn from. I am new to Android. I don't want to add `VideoView` in activity layout.

Answer (score 1):

you can add video view pragmatically like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
VideoView video = new VideoView(this);
video.setVideoURI("yourURI");
video.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(550, 550));
layout.addView(video);
```

Comment: @lchigoYme and what if there are multiple videos in my folder? How can i set multiple VideoViews according to number of videos?